# VS 2017 Community Edition Cannot Login to Microsoft

Tags: visual-studio-2017

Help! I cannot continue using Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition because every time I Sign in, it just stays on this page:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suggestions:

- Ensure you are on the latest VS version
- Try to load a solution before signing in
- Try to login via *Visual Studio > Help > Send Feedback > Report a problem*

Comment: - I can load a solution but the Sign in to your account Window will pop-up and I cannot click anywhere outside of it. Either I sign in or close Visual Studio.

Comment: Try the last point.

Comment: The sign-in page is gone now and I am already signed in. Thank you.